# Onde ficam as dependências de um projeto Maven e como rodá-lo?

Tags: java, maven, dependências

Comecei a usar o Maven há poucos minutos atrás, criei o projeto utilizando o *archetype* padrão (quickstart), removendo apenas o `junit`, pois não quero fazer testes, e adicionando o `jasypt`.

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Eu compilei o projeto no Maven, usando o `mvn package`, e ele gerou a pasta `target`. Mas como eu rodo o meu programa agora? Dentro da pasta `classes` só tem o meu código e eu não acho em nenhum lugar a pasta das dependências.

Pesquisei na internet sobre, alguns sites falam que ficam salvas, por padrão, no local de instalação do Maven, mas também não encontrei nada.

Comment: No próprio console/terminal/cmd é exibido o local aonde o jar foi salvo, algo como `C:\Foo\bar\projeto\target\projetodojean-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, esse jar é o seu "programa". Obs: se usar `mvn install` o comando vai copiar o seu .jar ou .war para a pasta `.m2` (em Windows `C:/Users/<usuario>/.m2/` em Linux `~/.m2/`) e vai copiar o .pom também. De qualquer forma o seu programa é o .jar (ou .war, dependendo do que usa).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Onde ficam as dependências?

As dependências ficam na pasta `.m2`, que por sua vez fica na pasta *home* do seu usuário, que varia conforme o sistema operacional:

| SO | Pasta |
| --- | --- |
| Windows | `C:\Users\<username>\.m2` |
| Linux | `/home/<username>/.m2` |
| Mac | `/Users/<username>/.m2` |

No Linux e Mac também é possível acessar como `~/.m2` (já que `~` é o [atalho](https://askubuntu.com/a/656886) para a *home* do usuário).

Dentro da pasta `.m2` existe a pasta `repository`, e é lá que ficam as dependências. É uma pasta centralizada, assim se dois projetos usarem a mesma versão da mesma dependência, não será necessário baixá-la novamente.

Por exemplo, ao adicionar o jasypt nas dependências e rodar `mvn package`, podemos ver nas mensagens o momento em que ela é baixada:

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.3/jasypt-1.9.3.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.3/jasypt-1.9.3.pom (8.1 kB at 20 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.3/jasypt-1.9.3.jar
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.3/jasypt-1.9.3.jar (142 kB at 190 kB/s)
```

E se olharmos na pasta `~/.m2/repository/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.3/`, veremos que lá estão os respectivos arquivos desta dependência.

---

## Como rodar

Para rodar o projeto, você pode usar o [`exec-maven-plugin`](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/). No seu `pom.xml`, adicione-o dentro de `<pluginManagement><plugins>`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>nome.completo.da.classe.incluindo.pacote.MainClass</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Eu omiti a tag `<version>`, assim [ele busca a versão mais recente do *plugin*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28791722), mas se quiser uma versão específica, basta colocá-la abaixo do `artifactId`.

Depois, rode:

```bash
mvn compile exec:java
```

E pronto! Sem o `compile`, ele roda a última versão do código que foi compilada, mas se você mudou o código e quer rodar a versão atualizada, use `compile`. Repare que não precisa rodar `mvn package`.

Com isso, o próprio Maven já carrega as dependências no *classpath*. Claro que você poderia rodar diretamenta na linha de comando, algo como:

```bash
# depois de feito o "mvn package" para gerar o jar do meu projeto, faça:
java -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.3/jasypt-1.9.3.jar:target/meuprojeto-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar nome.completo.da.classe.incluindo.pacote.MainClass

# ou, se não tiver o jar (por exemplo, se só compilou com "mvn compile"):
java -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.3/jasypt-1.9.3.jar:target/classes nome.completo.da.classe.incluindo.pacote.MainClass
```

Mas conforme o número de dependências aumenta, isso se torna desnecessariamente complicado. Usando `mvn exec:java`, o Maven já cuida dessa parte "burocrática" para você.

Obs: da forma que está a configuração acima, ele sempre vai rodar a classe que está especificada na tag `mainClass`. Mas se quiser, pode remover esta tag e colocar a classe que quer rodar na própria linha de comando:

```bash
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="pacote.OutraClasse"
```

---

#### Alternativa

Outra opção é gerar um único jar gigante com todas as dependências. Para isso você precisa do [`maven-assembly-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/). No `pom.xml` adicione:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <mainClass>nome.completo.da.classe.incluindo.pacote.MainClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
      <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Não precisa do `groupId`, pois segundo a própria [documentação](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html):

> *We don't need a groupId specification because the group is org.apache.maven.plugins ...which is assumed by default.*

Depois rode:

```bash
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

E na pasta `target` será gerado um arquivo `meuprojeto-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. Para rodá-lo:

```bash
java -jar target/meuprojeto-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Assim, ele rodará a classe que foi especificada na tag `mainClass`. Se quiser rodar outra classe, basta mudar para:

```bash
java -cp target/meuprojeto-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar pacote.OutraClasse
```

Como o jar já tem todas as dependências, basta incluí-lo no *classpath* e especificar a outra classe que quer rodar.

O detalhe, claro, é que esse arquivo pode ficar gigante, conforme o número de dependências aumenta. Neste caso simples ele só incluiu as classes do meu projeto e do jasypt. Mas imagine um projeto maior, com várias dependências (que por sua vez podem ter outras dependências, etc). Claro que cada caso é um caso, e pode ser que valha a pena ou seja realmente necessário ter um único jar gigante com tudo.

Se quiser que o arquivo não tenha o sufixo `jar-with-dependencies`, basta adicionar `<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>` dentro de `configuration`.

---

## Mudar a pasta do repositório

Em vez de usar `.m2/repository`, é possível mudar a pasta do repositório local. Você pode colocar esta configuração no [arquivo `settings.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html):

```xml
<settings>
    <localRepository>/outra/pasta</localRepository>
```

Ou mudar na linha de comando:

```bash
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=/outra/pasta etc...
```

<sup><sub>*Mas sinceramente, eu nunca precisei disso...*</sub></sup>

Comment: Mas eu não tenho essa pasta `repository` no diretório. Só tenho a `bin`, `boot`, `conf` e `lib`.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Vc está olhando na pasta em que o Maven está instalado, mas o repository fica na pasta `.m2`

Comment: Ah... Obrigado! rsrs